# hyper::Error(Parse(Method))

Tags: error

The log output is as follows:

```
2023-03-06 06:12:54 ✨ Imported #2 (0xbbb2…9e44)
2023-03-06 06:12:54 Accepting new connection 1/6
2023-03-06 06:12:55 HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method))
2023-03-06 06:12:55 Accepting new connection 1/6
2023-03-06 06:12:55 HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method))
2023-03-06 06:12:56 Accepting new connection 1/6
2023-03-06 06:12:56 HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method))
2023-03-06 06:12:56 Accepting new connection 1/6
2023-03-06 06:12:56 HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method))
2023-03-06 06:12:57  Idle (0 peers), best: #2 (0xbbb2…9e44), finalized #0 (0x25ff…4023), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2023-03-06 06:13:00  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0xbbb23b904a7058a68c12d7f5270d388aa6fa3a6fe67609ece14be14d3f249e44
2023-03-06 06:13:00  Prepared block for proposing at 3 (0 ms) [hash: 0x5d86b31f614600f13cf5a02fee5b21d8ca54adaad2f9698ce6f088b42bfbc223; parent_hash: 0xbbb2…9e44; extrinsics (1): [0x61c0…89ad]]
2023-03-06 06:13:00  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 3. Hash now 0x8f4e0c9713d8c09528fc0ee97e8760362871e927b332ec8e6acb42d2f8475dab, previously 0x5d86b31f614600f13cf5a02fee5b21d8ca54adaad2f9698ce6f088b42bfbc223.
2023-03-06 06:13:00 ✨ Imported #3 (0x8f4e…5dab)
2023-03-06 06:13:02  Idle (0 peers), best: #3 (0x8f4e…5dab), finalized #1 (0xd309…f431), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2023-03-06 06:13:02 Accepting new connection 1/6
2023-03-06 06:13:02 HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method))
2023-03-06 06:13:02 Accepting new connection 1/6
2023-03-06 06:13:02 HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method))
2023-03-06 06:13:03 Accepting new connection 1/6
2023-03-06 06:13:03 HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method))
2023-03-06 06:13:03 Accepting new connection 1/6
2023-03-06 06:13:03 HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method))
```

Start command:

```
./target/release/node-template \
--dev \
--port 30323 --ws-port 9924 --rpc-port 9923 \
--rpc-cors=all --rpc-external --ws-external \
--rpc-methods=unsafe \
--ws-max-connections 6
```

What is the problem???

Comment: Is your node running on a server with open ports? Maybe some bots try to connect to it.

Comment: This is an error that occurred while handling an HTTP stream, specifically a [parse error](https://docs.rs/hyper/latest/hyper/struct.Error.html). Most likely, it is a custom setup you have on your machine and not something that has to do with the node-template.

Comment: @Bruno hi,
What is the conclusion? How can we solve this?
Iam also facing the same issue `HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Parse(Method))` while connecting as validator to boot node
I have launched a substrate-node-template with AWS
I have opened ports as well, I have confirmed by checking metrics ports of two nodes

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi could you please help me here by looking above comment

Comment: I have this same problem with default 1.5.0 binaries and zombienet 1.3.91